# Asymptotic freedom in QCD

Tags: renormalization, quantum-chromodynamics, asymptotics

From renormalization group equation
$$
t \frac{d \bar{g}(t , g)}{dt} = \beta (\bar{g}(t , g)), \quad \bar{g}(1 , g) = g
$$
(here $t$ is momentum scale factor, $g$ is initial coupling constant and $\bar{g}$ is an effective coupling constant) and 
$$
\tag 1 \beta (g) = ag^{2}
$$
we can get
$$
\bar{g}(t , g) = \frac{g}{1 -  gln(t)a} .
$$
For QCD 
$$
\tag 2 a = c\left(-11 + \frac{2}{3}n_{f} \right), 
$$
where $n_{f} = 6$ is the number of quark types.

How to get that for QCD we asymptotically have $(1)$ and $(2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, equation (1) should be $\beta(g)=ag^3$. This is not an *asymptotic* formula. It is the *approximate* expression for the $\beta$ function to one loop order. Expression (2) is an *exact* expression at this order. The simplest method to compute this would be perform the computation in the *background field gauge*. Take a look a Peskin chapter 16 section 6 where this method is developed. This is a very efficient method to compute the $\beta$ function as it avoids the evaluation of numerous Feynman diagrams.

Comment: No, expression $\beta (g) = ag^{2}$ is right.

Comment: Yes you are right. I should have mentioned that both the expressions are correct modulo a numerical factor that can be absorbed in the constant 'a'. This can always be done by the redefinition of the coupling. Thanks for pointing out.